# Tomcat connection successful but unsuccessful in connecting to the database to get data

Tags: database, tomcat, backend

can someone help with this tomcat setup as it is my first time using tomcat. I have successfully setup tomcat but when run my project it successfully runs the tomcat but it did not connect to the database kept having error that says SSL connection error.

This is my url string setup and the java jdk version that im suing is 1.8.0. Im using macbook.

Comment: This is my url jdbc:sqlserver://10.125.31.16:1433;databaseName=;SelectMethod=cursor;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2

Comment: I have removed the <sql> tag, since this isn't related to the SQL _language_. Instead you should add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: Which database do you try to connect to with `databaseName=;`? Also: Please add this information to your question: You can (and should) always provide all information in your question ([ask])